# Show the record in a table as a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am having a table with the name `tbl_Criteria` and the columns available here are ID , Name.
and sample records are given below

```
D        Name
1        Lunch
2        Dinner
```

I am having an another table with the name `tbl_Feedback` which are having the column as given below

```
ID      UserID    Creteria      Ratings
1        129         2            A
2        329         2            B
3        520         1            C
```

My need is I need to show the list of creteria as the column and I need to give the ratings
as given below

```
Dinner  Lunch
A       C
B       Null
```

Hope this is clear. Please let me know if this is not.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pivoting data from rows into columns, there are a few ways that you can do this.  You could use an aggregate function with a CASE expression or since you are using SQL Server you could use the PIVOT function.  In both cases you will be applying some sort of aggregation with a group by.

Since you just want to display the `ratings` and the `name`, if you apply an aggregate function to the string column then you will return one row when using a `GROUP BY`.

The syntax using an aggregate function with a CASE will be:

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'Dinner' then ratings end) Dinner,
  max(case when name = 'Lunch' then ratings end) Lunch
from tbl_feedback f
inner join tbl_criteria c
  on f.creteria = c.d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ce91/5). But if you run the query above you will only return one row:

```
| DINNER | LUNCH |
------------------
|      B |     C |
```

So you need to include some value that will allow distinct rows to be included in the final result.  Since you are using SQL Server you can apply a `row_number()`.  If you include a `row_number()` you can partition the data by the `creteria` similar to the following:

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'Dinner' then ratings end) Dinner,
  max(case when name = 'Lunch' then ratings end) Lunch
from
(
  select f.ratings, c.name, 
    row_number() over(partition by f.creteria order by f.id) rn
  from tbl_feedback f
  inner join tbl_criteria c
    on f.creteria = c.d
) d
group by rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ce91/6).  The row_number generates a unique value that is needed when applying the group by.

You can also use the `row_number()` when using the PIVOT function:

```
select dinner, lunch
from
(
  select f.ratings, c.name, 
    row_number() over(partition by f.creteria order by f.id) rn
  from tbl_feedback f
  inner join tbl_criteria c
    on f.creteria = c.d
) d
pivot
(
  max(ratings)
  for name in (dinner, lunch)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ce91/8).  The final result with these queries will be:

```
| DINNER |  LUNCH |
-------------------
|      A |      C |
|      B | (null) |
```

Edit #1:  If you have an unknown or dynamic number of criteria names, then you will need to use dynamic sql to generate the result.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from tbl_Criteria
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
             (
                select f.ratings, c.name, 
                  row_number() over(partition by f.creteria order by f.id) rn
                from tbl_feedback f
                inner join tbl_criteria c
                  on f.creteria = c.d
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                max(ratings)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ce91/10)

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. 

You just mention "Lunch" and "Dinner" as hard coded in the select statement. But I can insert more records in that table tbl_createria.I need to select and show are the records that i have inserted in the tbl_creteria as the column. Hope this is clear sir. Please let me know if this is not.

Comment: @user2003780 See my edit, you will have to use dynamic sql to get the result if the values will be unknown.